# htaccess url rewrite issue. Cant handle the server structure with magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

i currently run a magento website:

http://shopfair.eu/domains/shopfair.eu/

as you can see the url is wrong: shopfair.eu/domains/ seems to be like the domains/ folder on the server.

i would like to erase the shopfair.eu/domains/ from the url and leave just the shopfair.eu/index.php

I think it can made via the url rewrite function of the .htaccess file, but after several try i cant figure how to do it. Any suggestion?

Best regards,
AR

Comment: What did you try? please show your code so that we can help you with that

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your ´.htaccess´ file